# save XML file in minified form using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xml

I want to save space by saving the xml file in minified  form

for example

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <div/>
  </div>
</body>
```

it should be saved like this

```
<body><div><p>hello</p><div/></div></body>
```

I'm using  DOMDocument to create xml file like this

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
        $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $xml->formatOutput = false;

        $feed = $xml->createElement("feed");
        $feed = $xml->appendChild($feed);
/*add attribute*/
        $feed_attribute        = $xml->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi');
        $feed_attribute->value = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
        $feed->appendChild($feed_attribute);
        $aggregator = $xml->createElement("aggregator");
        $aggregator = $feed->appendChild($aggregator);
        $name       = $xml->createElement('name', 'test.com');
        $aggregator->appendChild($name);
...etc
        $xml->save(public_path() .$string, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Comment: The `preserveWhiteSpace` and `formatOutput` in your example should take care of this: https://3v4l.org/BcHb8

Comment: yeah formatOutput  worked I was doing it in wrong way  thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already using the right options. `DOMDocument::$formatOutput` and `DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace`:

#### Format Output

`DOMDocument::$formatOutput` adds indentation whitespace nodes to an XML DOM if saved.  (It is disabled by default.)

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$body = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('body'));
$div = $body->appendChild($document->createElement('div'));
$div
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('p'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('hello'));

echo "Not Formatted:\n", $document->saveXML();

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo "\nFormatted:\n", $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
Not Formatted: 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<body><div><p>hello</p></div></body> 

Formatted: 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

However it does not indent if here are text child nodes. It tries to avoid changes to the text output of an HTML/XML document. So it will usually not reformat a loaded document with existing indention whitespace nodes.

#### Preserve White Space

`DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace` is an option for the parser. If disabled (It is enabled by default) the parser will ignore any text nodes that would consists of only whitespaces. Indentations are text nodes with a linebreak and some spaces or tabs. It can be used to remove indentations from an XML.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div> 
</body>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXML($xml);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<body><div><p>hello</p></div></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, you have to use saveXML() instead of save(),

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$xml->formatOutput = false;

$root = $xml->createElement('book');
$root = $xml->appendChild($root);

$title = $xml->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

$text = $xml->createTextNode("This is the \n title");
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

echo "Saving all the document:\n";

$xml_content = $xml->saveXML();
echo $xml_content . "\n";

$xml_content = str_replace(array(">\n", ">\t"), '>', trim($xml_content, "\n"));

echo $xml_content . "\n";

// Write the contents back to the file
$filename = "/tmp/xml_minified.xml";
file_put_contents($filename, $xml_content);
?>
```

Comment: it won't help  I'm using DOMDocument  to create and save the file

Comment: This will also strip any white-space from text nodes and attributes in the document, which feels a bit risky.

Comment: @iainn looks like you have not seen I am not replacing any spaces but `array("\n", "\t")`

Comment: @iainn also code for replacing \n & \t corrected, check by executing.

Comment: Why are you setting `preserveWhiteSpace` and `formatOutput` to false? Your comment even says *we want a nice output*, when that's the opposite of what we want. The original poster also said that the question was solved yesterday. Using `save` or `saveXML` also makes no different to the output, one just saves to a file instead of a string.

Comment: @iainn have you checked the output, It is what the original poster wanted...as the basic code was copied from some other site i forgot to remove the comment (now removed) and also it will be bad if we tell DOMDocument class to first add the formatting with white space & we will be removing it using our code.

I don't think there will be lots of cases in xml when "\n" will come after ">".
My solution is just another way of achieving the results.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the output, and it isn't valid. That `str_replace` line will remove all `>`s at the end of a line, including the XML document type, making the document invalid. If you remove that, and just let `DomDocument` do the job instead then it'll work fine. Ultimately, the only difference between your code and the code in the question is that you're using `saveXML` and `file_put_contents` instead of `save`, which doesn't provide any benefit

Comment: @iainn sorry, i got your point...now I am replacing ">\n" with ">", So, the invalid xml issue will be resolved.